# ERROR Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface 'App'

Tags: angular, firebase, npm

Trying to serve up my angularCLI and Firebase resulted in this error... What do I do?

> ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts(5,22):
>   error TS2420: Class 'FirebaseApp' incorrectly implements interface
>   'App'.   Property 'firestore' is missing in type 'FirebaseApp'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts(12,28): error
>   TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts(14,62):
>   error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts(15,48):
>   error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_list_observable.d.ts(16,92):
>   error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts(11,31): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts(12,37): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/database/firebase_object_observable.d.ts(13,24): error TS2694: Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(12,32): error TS2694:
>   Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(13,35): error TS2694:
>   Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(14,35): error TS2694:
>   Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>   node_modules/angularfire2/interfaces.d.ts(15,44): error TS2694:
>   Namespace 'firebase' has no exported member 'Promise'.
>
> webpack: Failed to compile.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "oshop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.9.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.6.7.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "author": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "imnickvaughn"
  }
}
```

Comment: The first thing you should do Is share the code where you are setting up firebase as it is impossible to give you an answer without see what you are doing

Comment: I just wanted to post my solution for others... I am hoping they'll find this when they search the error I posted and then try out my solutions.  Ill put in my package.json though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first try:
(if you have your angular cli and firebase installed)

1. In terminal type: npm install -S angularfire2@latest

once you do this your angularfire2 will read:
        "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",

...and thats it

If that's not enough look at these sources and try...
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1338
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4391

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

rm -rf node_modules dist
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
ng update [this wasn't working so I just changed it to ng init I believe]

npm install -g firebase-tools
npm install -S angularfire2@latest
```

Using the above advice and reinstalling all dependencies also works for this problem...
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid/issues/155

...Also the firebase command wouldn't work in my oh-my-zsh until I typed exactly:

```
npm install -S -D -g firebase-tools
```

Into vs code terminal.

Hopefully this saves someone an hour or five...

Comment: not working anymore: 
% npm install -S angularfire2@latest
npm WARN deprecated angularfire2@5.4.2: AngularFire has moved, we're now @angular/fire

Answer (score 3):

for me fix was changing FirebaseApp class to :

```
export declare class FirebaseApp implements FBApp {
name: string;
options: {};
auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
database: () => FirebaseDatabase;
messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
storage: () => FirebaseStorage;
delete: () => Promise<any>;
firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
automaticDataCollectionEnabled:boolean
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just downgrade firebase version using the following:

First, go to your project directory and then this command

```
 npm install --save firebase@3.9.*
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I just added `automaticDataCollectionEnabled:boolean` in class `FirebaseApp`.

It's work for me.

Answer (score 2):

do some changes in package json

"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6.0",
"firebase": "^4.12.1"

Answer (score 0):

**Solution():**

> **install this command in your firebase project**

```
npm i --save firebase@5.10.1 angularfire2@5.1.2
```

> **it will work.**

Answer (score 0):

I used this

```
export declare class FirebaseApp implements app.App {
    installations(): import("firebase").installations.Installations;
    performance(): import("firebase").performance.Performance;
    remoteConfig(): import("firebase").remoteConfig.RemoteConfig;
    analytics(): import("firebase").analytics.Analytics;
    name: string;
    options: {};
    auth: () => FirebaseAuth;
    database: (databaseURL?: string) => FirebaseDatabase;
    messaging: () => FirebaseMessaging;
    storage: (storageBucket?: string) => FirebaseStorage;
    delete: () => Promise<void>;
    firestore: () => FirebaseFirestore;
    functions: (region?: string) => FirebaseFunctions;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You getting below error ?**

ERROR in node_modules/angularfire2/app/firebase.app.module.d.ts(5,22)

webpack: Failed to compile.

Please don't do anything, just install latest version of **angularfire2**
npm install -S angularfire2@latest

Comment: you repeated my answer?